# Cocos2D - Find which display suffix is being used?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Is there an easy way to find which display suffix is in use?

I've tried taking a look through some of the Cocos2D internals but am struggling to find how it’s done.

Kind Regard

Comment: draw over each image with a different color and you'll see. Suffixes are processed in CCFileUtils.m

Comment: Thanks.  What I am looking for is a way to use the same suffix names in a function that loads a plist file.  Thought it may be easier to reuse some code than having to write an if statement to determine the right suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the *CCTextureCache.m*. I suggest you put a debugger in the *addImage:* method and inspect the *fullpath* variable. This method is used to load the images to the texture cache and the *fullpath* shows exactly which resource is being used.